# How do I style an element inside an img attribute

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style the 'yeep' attribute inside an img tag. You can see my attempt in the css code, but its's not working. My goal is to be able to individually style the text inside each paragraph box after you click on an image. I'm new to programming, so can you guys tell me what I'm doing wrong? If you have any questions let me know. Thanks

```js
function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');
  imgParagraph.innerHTML = imgs.getAttribute("yeep");

  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
  imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  opacity: 0.85;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 5000px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  width: 20%;
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 120px;
}
#img[yeep] {
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 600px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 830px) and (min-width: 760px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 759px) and (min-width: 646px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/styleprojects.css" />
    <script src='../Javascript/script.js'></script>
    <title>Projects</title>
</head>
<body class='totalbody'>

  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </header>

  <div>
    <div id="expanded-wrapper">
      <img id="expandedImg">
      <p id="img-paragraph"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" yeep="Parapraph #1" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://s.yimg.com/ny/api/res/1.2/Petngc9GmDGVfvqWtZW1uw--/YXBwaWQ9aGlnaGxhbmRlcjt3PTcwNTtoPTM4MC43/https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/p2FH9i2oATkHA6O0ucuC9A--~B/aD0yMTY7dz00MDA7c209MTthcHBpZD15dGFjaHlvbg--/https://media.zenfs.com/en/prnewswire.com/d908212583d777d158af74cb171ec897"
        alt="Snow" style="width:100%" yeep="Parapraph #2" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://engineering.wustl.edu/news/PublishingImages/141020_jwb_brookings_007-1915x768.jpg?RenditionID=1" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" yeep="Parapraph #3" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/McKelvey-courtyard.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" yeep="Parapraph #4" onclick="myFunction(this);">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you doing with the attribute "yeep"? It won't be displayed anywhere so   background-color:blue; won't do anything. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This isn't the whole code. I will update the whole code to show what it does in a larger context.

Comment: It's updated. Please take a look when you get a change

Comment: Refer to the answer I posted for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stylize the different paragraph texts wrapping the `yeep` text in a `p` tag with a `class` attached. Then style that class with css.

Example:

```js
function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');
  imgParagraph.innerHTML = imgs.getAttribute("yeep");

  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
  imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  opacity: 0.85;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 5000px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  width: 20%;
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 120px;
}
#img[yeep] {
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 600px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 830px) and (min-width: 760px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 759px) and (min-width: 646px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

.yeep1 {
  color: red;
}

.yeep2 {
  color: purple;
}

.yeep3 {
  color: green;
}
.yeep4 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/styleprojects.css" />
    <script src='../Javascript/script.js'></script>
    <title>Projects</title>
</head>
<body class='totalbody'>

  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </header>

  <div>
    <div id="expanded-wrapper">
      <img id="expandedImg">
      <p id="img-paragraph"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep1'> Parapraph #1 </p>" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://s.yimg.com/ny/api/res/1.2/Petngc9GmDGVfvqWtZW1uw--/YXBwaWQ9aGlnaGxhbmRlcjt3PTcwNTtoPTM4MC43/https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/p2FH9i2oATkHA6O0ucuC9A--~B/aD0yMTY7dz00MDA7c209MTthcHBpZD15dGFjaHlvbg--/https://media.zenfs.com/en/prnewswire.com/d908212583d777d158af74cb171ec897"
        alt="Snow" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep2'> Parapraph #2 </p>" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://engineering.wustl.edu/news/PublishingImages/141020_jwb_brookings_007-1915x768.jpg?RenditionID=1" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep3'> Parapraph #3 </p>" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/McKelvey-courtyard.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep4'> Parapraph #4 </p>" onclick="myFunction(this);">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```